# Show bad character in latin1_spanish_ci issue in php

Tags: php

I have this database that I can't modify

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (

  `extracto` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I need to show in JSON in a PHP webservice but I get bad characters

I add   mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
but the issue still appears.

extracto: "Solicitando al D.E,informe referente a saldos conciliados con las empresas prestadoras de servicios de publicidad y propaganda registrados por la Administración Central del municipio.-"

Thanks!

Comment: possibly you will have to transcribe the whole table in the new charset,or else dynamicaly re-encode it in utf8 charset, upon every fetch of data from that table

Comment: What code are you using; what results do you get; what results do you want?

Comment: I use $var  = utf8_encode($rowEmp["extracto"]); and nothing

http://transparenciamdp.com.ar/dd/devolverExpedientes.php?key=anio&value=2015

see extracto with the bad symbols